# Protected setters for jpa entity fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Is it good idea to make, for example, setter for id field of jpa entity protected? So other developers can't access it, therefore eliminating possible errors. Is there any pitfalls of such decision?
Here is example of what I am talking about, here Lombok is used to generate setters/getters:

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    public class User {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
        private Long id;
    
        @NaturalId
        @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
        @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
        private UUID uuid;
        
        public User(UUID uuid) {
            this.uuid = uuid;
        }
    
        //other fields 
    }
```

Also, I would be grateful for other recommendation regarding my code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what project structure/architecture are you going to use. Usually it is package by layer

> In the Package by Layer, Controllers , Services , and Repositories are
> placed in different single packages, so the whole application consists
> of three packages — except util — and packages have a large number of
> members.

It mean that protected setters methods will be visible just into that own package and subclasses. And if you will need it in another place you will can’t use it.

In case if you are going to use structure/architecture  Package-by-feature

> Package-by-feature uses packages to reflect the feature set. It tries
> to place all items related to a single feature (and only that feature)
> into a single directory/package. This results in packages with high
> cohesion and high modularity, and with minimal coupling between
> packages.

You are free to make setters methods as protected one or package default.

But in real world we know that always exist somethings that make us to do some changes.

According to encapsulation:

To allow outside access to the instance variables, public methods called getters and setters are defined, which are used to retrieve and modify the values of the instance variables, respectively. By using getters and setters, the class can enforce its own data validation rules and ensure that its internal state remains consistent.

You have to make setters and getters methods `public` by default.

About your case, in my opinion the access modifiers to setters method of id fields also should be public based on above details that I wrote